How to improve the site stats?
As the user @SRKX underlined in the answer the percentage of marked answers is pretty low (about 78%) and, cause of this reason, the quantitative finance site is still beta.
I noted that a lot of people, particularly the new users, do not mark the question as answered and, although the answer could be good enough, the question results to be unanswered.
May the community mark the question as an answer in the case there are good reasons to do that (a lot of upvotes, complete answer,...)?
In this way, according to me, the percentage of answered question increase and the site could still grow. What do you think?

I doubt anyone can mark an answer as accepted except for the user who asked the original question. That's the way the StackExchange is designed.
What can be done instead is gently nudging users to accept good answers by posting comments inviting them to accept, e.g. "Please consider accepting one of the answers below if you think that your question has been satisfactorily answered."
Anyway, there will always be users who won't bother registering on the site, voting or accepting answers.
